# Slowly moving an object to a new position in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

I have a car object in my scene. I would like to simulate a basic driving animation by moving it to a new position slowly... I have used the code below but I think I'm using Lerp wrong? It just jumps forward a bit and stops?

```
void PlayIntro() {
    GameObject Car = carObject;
    Vector3 oldCarPos = new Vector3(Car.transform.position.x, Car.transform.position.y, Car.transform.position.z);
    GameObject posFinder = GameObject.Find("newCarPos");

    Vector3 newCarPos = new Vector3(posFinder.transform.position.x, posFinder.transform.position.y, posFinder.transform.position.z);

    carObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (oldCarPos, newCarPos, Time.deltaTime * 2.0f);
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's two problems with your code:

- `Vector3.Lerp` returns a single value. Since your function will only be called once, you're just setting the position to whatever `Lerp` returns. You will want to change the position every frame instead. To do this, use [coroutines](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html).
- `Time.DeltaTime` returns the time that has passed since the last frame, which will generally be a very small number. You will want to pass in a number ranging from `0.0` to `1.0` depending the progress of the movement.

Your code will then look like this:

```
IEnumerator MoveFunction()
{
    float timeSinceStarted = 0f;
    while (true)
    {
        timeSinceStarted += Time.DeltaTime;
        obj.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(obj.transform.position, newPosition, timeSinceStarted);

        // If the object has arrived, stop the coroutine
        if (obj.transform.position == newPosition)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        // Otherwise, continue next frame
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is immediately after the Lerp function actually set the object's position to the desired position

here's what it should look like

```
carObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (oldCarPos, newCarPos, Time.deltaTime * 2.0f);
carObject.transform.position = newCarPos;
```

Comment: Hi @Matt, the code is working fine but this way the gameobject moves to fast, Do you know how can I make the movement slowly? I've already tried changing the value 2.0f from (Time.deltaTime * 2.0f). Thanks in advance